# angular module is not available

Tags: angularjs-module

This is surely a noob question but I just can't seem to figure out what is wrong with this simple module initiation ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F9JDS/)):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

I get an error saying that "Module 'myApp' is not available!". Does anyone know why this does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because (in the fiddle at least) that the script is run on `window.onload`, thus angular cannot find the module before it sees in the DOM that there should be a module named `myApp`.

before it was (in the head):

```
window.onload = function() {
    angular.module(...)
}
```

but it had to be:

```
angular.module(...)
```

ie. not waiting until the document was fully loaded, thus creating the module before angular sees that it should bootstrap the module `myApp`.

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F9JDS/3/)

Comment: You're right, that did fix the jsfiddle one. And I also found out why my offline example did not work. For some reason a Notepad++ plugin decided to format my HTML, including the reference to my script file where I put the module initialization. For some insane reason the plugin thought that <script src... /> was better than <script src...></script>

Comment: @boomshanka you should file a bug report to the maintainers of that plugin :) HTH

Comment: Yeah that would be the right thing to do - either that or get myself a decent angular IDE :-)

Comment: Not specific to this particular case but may help some (this post appears pretty high on google for this issue search): if your module is in a separate file, it also has to be included in the html: <script src="js/services.js"></script>